# Errors when Numerically Solving Differential Equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages

I am attempting to numerically integrate the equation 
$$\frac{\mathrm{dP} }{\mathrm{d} r}=-\left ( P+\rho\left ( r \right ) \right )\frac{m\left ( r \right )+4\pi r^{3}P}{r\left [ r-2m\left ( r \right ) \right ]}$$
to find $P\left ( r \right )$. I have defined the following:
$$\rho\left ( r \right )=\rho_{c}\left [ 1-\left ( \frac{r}{R} \right )^{2} \right ]$$
$$m\left ( r \right )=\frac{4\pi \rho_{c}\left ( 5r^{3}R^{2}-3r^{5} \right )}{15R^{2}}.$$
From here, I need to solve for $$ \frac{d\phi}{dr} = \frac{m(r) + 4\pi r^3 P}{r(r - 2m(r))}. $$
Currently, I am stuck on solving for $P$. I am getting an infinite expression 1/0 error (`Power::infy`) and a non numerical value at r==0 error (`NDSolve::ndnum`). My code is as follows:

```
R = 10000
pc = 7*10^17
Pc = 1.6*10^34
m[r_] := 4*Pi*pc*(5*r^3*R^2 - 3*r^5)/(15*R^2)
p[r_] := pc*(1 - (r/R)^2)
P = NDSolve[{y'[r] == -(y[r] + p[r])*(m[r] + 4*Pi*r^3*y[r])/(r*(r - 2*m[r])), 
    y[0] == Pc}, y, {r, 10, R - 10}]
```

How can I resolve this problem? Also, once this is resolved, how can I then find $\phi\left ( r \right )$? I am very new to Mathematica, so if you can poste some actual code, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Your initial condition `y[0] == Pc` makes `NDSolve` start at `r == 0`; since you divide by `r` in your ODE, you get the errors.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I have made the correction to `y[Rstart] == Pc]` where Rstart is 100. I am now getting a `NDSolve::ndsz`. I'm thinking this may be because my parameters are so large, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Any ideas?